# Конвертация 6 int в long long?

Tags: c++

Доброе время суток , задача 6 чисел размером int с разной битностью (17 бит, 7 бит ,17 бит, 7 бит , 13 бит, 3 бита) вложить в переменную unsigned long long размером в 64 бита .

Comment: Покажите конкретно, что вам нужно сделать. Вы можете просто присвоить значение типа int переменной типа long long int или же сделать приведение типов. Так что ваша проблема не понятна.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow: Думаю, ТС хочет код. Посоветуйте ему какую-нибудь хорошую книгу по C++. До прочтения книги, думаю, код давать не имеет смысла.

Comment: @VladD Думаю, что TC нужен ответ срочно и сейчас.:) Книга ему будет полезна как мертвому припарки.:)

Comment: 6 значений int заносятся в 1 переменную long long после из этой переменной вытягиваются 6 тех же самых значений int

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Как думаешь, писать ему пример с union объединяющем побитово в одно поле или пусть в интернете ищет как создавать битовые поля и делать юнионы. Ну либо как вариант пусть изучит битовые операции и сдвиги

Comment: @user2420249 Ты вопрос нормально сформулируй. Ибо long long обычно 8 байт, а int 4 байта. Как ты хочешь 6*4=24 байта запихнуть в 8

Comment: unsignet long long , извините ,поправил

Comment: Наверно, инты маленькие, скажем, не больше 2 байт. Тогда можно попытаться запихивать их в 8-байтовый длинный-длинный инт по принципу стека при помощи сдвигов влево.

Comment: int большие 1)17 2)7 3)17 4)7 5)13 6)3 как раз выходит на 64

Comment: @user2420249 Вот и не называй их int'ами. Если бы сразу представлял в голове их как 'битовые поля' то может быть и ответ в гугле нашел...

Comment: Кстати, никаких гарантий того, что `long long int` длиннее 6 байт стандарт не дает....

Comment: разве стандарт вообще дает какую-то гарантию относительно битовых размеров каких-то типов (кроме char)?

Comment: Да с битностью тяжело конечно, я пример пишу, а самого подмывает написать какое нибудь `_u64`... А потом еще искать в каких хеадерах в системе оно может быть описано. Я кстати так и на понял в какой момент long long на x86 архитектуре стал 8 байтным. Ведь если на современных x86 камнях компилить в 32 битном режиме вроде все равно 64 бита будет под long long.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Можно просто подготовить структуру в виде битовых полей, накладываемую на тот же адрес в памяти, что и long long:

```
 typedef struct {
   union { // union говорит, что все что в нем, на самом деле находится в одном месте в памяти
           unsigned long long full; // Основной long long
          struct {           // Битовые поля, после двоеточия кол-во бит
           unsigned long long int1:17;// При этом тип данных перед переменными пишем максимальный
           unsigned long long int2:7; // Если написать меньшего размера
           unsigned long long int3:17;// то компилятор может не влезающие целиком в очередное поле 
           unsigned long long int4:7; // перенести в следующее, и в итоге не влезет в 64 бита
           unsigned long long int5:13;
           unsigned long long int6:3;
          } i;
   };
 } myLong; // Ну вот так назовем наш тип данных

int main()
 {
  myLong L; // Объявляем переменную L нашего нового типа
  L.full=0; // не забываем сбросить всю ее в 0

  L.i.int1=1; // Вот так обращаемся к битовым полям внутри структуры
  L.i.int6=7;
  printf("%LX\n",L.full); // Печатаем полное поле long long
 }
```

Comment: ага всё понял , вот только не понял как выводить отдельные значения L.i.int1 например , какой параметр для printf ? 

ибо вот так работает
`L.i.int1=123;
printf("%llu\n",L.i.int1);
`
но если так 
`L.i.int1=130999;
printf("%llu\n",L.i.int1);
`
то выводит не правильно (

Comment: printf не поймет такого. лучше сделай простую переменную типа int и скопируй в нее перед выводом

Comment: `L.i.int1=130999;
int ad=0;
ad=L.i.int1;
 cout<<ad<<endl;
`
на выходе -73

Comment: @user2420249 Так, конечно, ошибка в структуре, старший бит 17 битного числа оказывается знаком :) В структуре все long long сделать unsigned. Правлю ответ

Comment: Спасибо примерно понял.

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int a = 1, b = 2, c = 3, d = 4, e = 5, f = 6;
    unsigned long long longint;
    unsigned long long temp;
    const int mask = 0xFF;
    if (sizeof(longint) < 6) {
        std::cout << "oops" << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }
    longint = a & mask;
    temp = (b & mask) << 8;
    longint |= temp;
    temp = (c & mask) << 16;
    longint |= temp;
    // ...
    std::cout << longint << std::endl;
}
```

Как-то так...
Вообще, лучше `temp = b & mask; temp <<= 8;`

По уточненному варианту:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int a = 1, b = 2, c = 3, d = 4, e = 5, f = 6;
    unsigned long long longint;
    unsigned long long temp;
    const int mask_a = 0b11111111111111111;
    const int mask_b = 0b1111111;
    const int mask_c = 0b11111111111111111;
    if (sizeof(longint) < 6) {
        std::cout << "oops" << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }
    longint = a & mask_a;
    temp = b & mask_b; longint |= temp << 17;
    temp = c & mask_c; longint |= temp << (17 + 7);
    // ...
    std::cout << longint << std::endl;
}
```

Но 0b... вообще, только с 14-го стандарта...

Comment: Ага, а потом пойди, объясни ему, какие битовые маски писать для распаковки обратно и как их считать :) Хотя конечно такие знания для программера крайне полезны...

Comment: @Mike `0xFF, 0xFF00 ...`, чо их писать-то)))

Comment: Ты не дочитал его последних комментариев, у него "инты" видите ли по 3, 7, 13, и 17 бит :)

Comment: @Mike, думаю, это не биты, это значения "больших int"

Comment: всё верно Mike 7 17 13 3 бита

Comment: @user2420249, немного повторюсь, опять же, никаких гарантий, что 17 бит влезет в int - нет. Но, если 17 и т.д. это размер в битах изначальных 6 чисел(?), то лучше первый ответ, или сдвиги и маски писать конкретно под нужное числ битов.